# Java String array Output Difference

Tags: java

```
String s="StackOverflow is heaven";
char []c=new Char[100];

c=s.toCharArray();

System.out.println(c);
System.out.println("Output="+c);

Output is :-  StackOverflow is heaven
              Output=[C@15db9742
```

Why there is a difference B/w outputs? Please Explain it

Comment: You are getting the address printed in the second print. But i dint know why. IS you first print correct? Is it not println(s)?

Comment: When you print an array, It will print the address of the array. Not the content in it. If you want that char[] to be a string use 'new string(c)'.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. OP probably knows how to print an array, he just wonders why the reference is printed in the second case.

Comment: It's printed because an array is essentially a subclass of `Object`, which doesn't override the default `#toString` (so it prints the `#hashcode` as well as the class type, in this case a `char`-primitive array aka `[C`).

Comment: Replace the lines and then check what u get.

Comment: @Rogue It doesn't work with `int[]`, so I'm not sure your explanation be correct.  Apologies to everyone for marking duplicate so quickly; this is a good question, one of the few good ones all afternoon.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen An `int[]` prints `[I@hashcode`? Try it yourself: `System.out.println(new int[] {1, 2, 3});`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen May be you are trying to do `c = s.toCharArray();` ?? after changing it to `int[]`.

Comment: @SureshAtta [You get gibberish with an int array](http://rextester.com/DZH6426).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't see any gibberish there. It is just your Integer arrays hex code. Just like char array.

Comment: Which lines I have to replace ?? @pawan sharma

Comment: Just interchange / shuffle the lines

Answer (score 5):

Case1 :

The [overloaded println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[])) which takes `char[]` method processed your array internally and printed the String.  Note that `println()` has no such overloaded method for any other type of primitive array.

Case2 :

You are concatenating the array with String , hence before even processing by println, step 1 itself that your char arrays `toString()` gets called and appended to string and the final output printed as a String.

So if you expand your second statement, the processing looks like

```
System.out.println("Output="+c.toString());  
System.out.println("Output="+ "[C@15db9742");
System.out.println("Output=[C@15db9742");
```

Comment: When toString() method is called it append with string but final answer printed is String with the address of char Array[] Which I am not getting why?

Comment: @ManishSharma The "address-of..." mumbo-jumbo is just what `toString()` does for `char` arrays :-(.  It's probably inheriting the default behavior from `Object`...